# Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in Java (Basic XSS)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, xss, veracode

I am using `Veracode` to validate my code, getting error "CWE–80: Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS)" for the line "return collectionService.getAllNotificationDrop()" in the below method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "loadAllNotification", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<UserVO> loadAllNotification() {
        try {
            **return collectionService.getAllNotificationDrop();**
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.debug(e);
             return null;
        }

    }




public List<UserVO> getAllNotificationDrop() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Entered new method ====> getAllNotificationDrop() ");
        List<UserVO> users;
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        try {
            users = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT login_id as userId,first_name||' '||last_name as firstName "
                    + " FROM user_master")
                    .addScalar("userId", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
                    .addScalar("firstName", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
                    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(UserVO.class))
                    .list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Error in getAllNotificationDrop",e);
        } finally {
            session.clear();
        }
        LOGGER.info("Method End ====> getAllNotificationDrop() ");
        return users;
    }
```

Please help to resolve this issue, no clue for last few days.

Comment: I think there is no direct problem with the code you've shown. The problem may be in `collectioniService.getAllNotificationDrop()`, apparently some user input gets reflected in there. It may also be a false positive, static scanners are not perfect, but based on my experience, Veracode XSS findings are usually valid.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, updated with the code. any idea, whats wrong here?